# Using an optional parameter in C# as an Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

i have this code:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]GetFilesRequest request)
```

If request is **null**, I want to create a new **GetFilesRequest**, because in the constructor I did this to create default params of the class:

```
public GetFilesRequest()
    {
        Sort = "latest";
        Filter = "";
    }
```

So I'm thinking about:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]GetFilesRequest request = new GetFilesRequest)
```

But I'm getting this warning:

```
'request' is of type 'GetFilesRequest'. A default parameter value of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null.
```

Comment: So instead of a default value (allow null to be default), why not just run a check at the beginning of the method, check for null and instantiate?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. But that doesnt scale. Imagine I have 500 other GET method, should do that in every single one?

Comment: Probably, you're going to be doing the default value thing in those 500 methods anyways. This isn't going to change much (and its pretty much the only way according to the answers)

Answer (score 6):

No - the default value must be a compile-time constant.  Can you use an overload instead?

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
     return Get(new GetFilesRequest());
}
```

Comment: Forget it, I just understood your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can only use a constant value that the compiler can create. What you have would require a runtime object allocation, so that's why the compiler is complaining. Try something like this.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]GetFilesRequest request = null) {
    request = request ?? new GetFilesRequest();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. But that doesnt scale. Imagine I have 500 other GET method, should do that in every single one?

Comment: Well, do you in fact have 500 other get methods? I think you could write a custom custom model binder to make a new instance for every parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates this is not possible as a parameter.  However you can restructure the code as such

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]GetFilesRequest request = null)
{
   if (request == null) request = new GetFilesRequest();

   // TODO : Remaining method body
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. But that doesnt scale. Imagine I have 500 other GET method, should do that in every single one?

Comment: I do not quite understand, how does it not scale? In terms of typing or in terms of performance?  If it's the former, the code is an additional line that meets your constraints, whether its in the method signature or in the body - it has to be written. If the it's that later, the cost of performing an additional null check is negligible and will not have a noticeable impact for 500 methods.

Comment: If I have required fields, or validations of any type. I'll need to be checking them using ifs instead of filters